# Can I attach a login form's username into the URL as a query string parameter?

Tags: asp.net, url, authentication

I have a standard Login form

`<asp:Login ID="lgnExcel" DestinationPageUrl="login/data.aspx"  OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" runat="server">`

Is it possible to attach the Username as a query string with the DestinationPageUrl or reference the value in the code behind. I've tried `lgnExcel.UserName.ToString()` but coudldn't get to show any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just grab the username from the User.Identity.Name field on the destination page?

Comment: Well what I want to do is grab the default value and insert it into a database. I know how to display it but I want the raw text/value in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Alright for future lurkers to get the value of your username in you code behind try { `string getname = Page.User.Identity.Name;` } and you can retain the value across pages.

-Cheers.

Comment: Thats the same thing @Chris Lively put up

Comment: Not exactly... I mean he DID add "string getname = Page" lol. Maybe he's going for the Self Learner badge?